# How do I make my security group accessible only to my IP address?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-vpc

I have an EC2 instance for running RServer. I've set up my security group, but AWS sent me a warning saying that my EC2 instance is accessible to anyone in the world.

This is my setup.

I have a VPC with `IPv4 CIDR 10.0.0.0/16`.

I have two subnets, each in a different availability zone. They are both associated with the VPC.

They both have these same rules. [image]

They are both connected with the same internet gateway, which is also attached to the VPC.

For route tables, they both have `10.0.0.0/16` with target `local`.

They also have a connection with another route table. Each of them connects with a different route table.

The first connects with route table A, which has two routes. It has `10.0.0.0/16 local active Propagated: No` and `0.0.0.0/0 active Propagated: No`. The second route is connected with the same internet gateway as the VPC.

The second subnet connects with route table B, which has the same routes as route table A.

I also have a security group. It is associated with the VPC. It has three inbound rules. The first one is type: SSH, Protocol: TCP, Port Range: 22 and source as my personal ip address followed by `/32`.

The second one is for RStudio Server and is type: Custom TCP Rule, Protocol: TCP, Port Range: 0.0.0.0/0 and the third one is also for RStudio Server and is type: Custom TCP Rule, Protocol: TCP, Port Range: ::/0.

I also have a network ACL which has default settings. It allows all inbound and outbound traffic.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have typo for the RStudio IP range, which is 0.0.0.0/0, why don't restrict to limited IPs rather than global accessible? Even if it's TCP, you still need to limit the IP range

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're saying. What should the RStudio IP range be? I was told it needed to be accessible to everything on port 8787

Comment: @Cauder 0.0.0.0/0 **means** "open to the world."  Open it only to where you need to access it from.

Comment: Sweet. I should change that IP Range to only my IP address.

Answer (score 1):

The pictures you have provided are for Network Access Control Lists (NACLs), not Security Groups. In general, **you should never change the NACL configuration** unless you really understand networking.

Rather, you should configure your **Security Group** to only permit inbound access from your IP address on the desired ports.

Comment: I appreciate the guideline "avoid NACL if you can config a Security Group". Thanks!